# How to call win32 dll in windows 7

Tags: c#, dllimport

From within a C# application(Visual Studio 2008) i am calling a win32 dll using DllImport. Everything works fine in Windows XP. However when i use the same exe and dll in Windows 7, the win32 dll fails to get loaded. Do i need to write any extra code to invoke a win32 dll from Windows 7 ?

Comment: Is the XP 32bit and the Windows 7 64bit ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before building the C# program, make sure that in Visual studio Configuration Manager you choose "x86" and not "any CPU" as the platform. If any CPU is selected, your C# application runs as a 64bit process in Windows 7 and tries to load the 32-bit win32 dll in to the 64-bit process which would fail as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265023/load-32bit-dll-library-in-64bit-application) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Is your windows 7 64 bit?

Is you .NET exe marked as AnyCPU?

If the answer is yes to the above then you need to mark you .exe as x86 via the Configuration manager in Visual Studio.