# Erlang: Using 32 bit NIFs under a 64 bit VM

Tags: erlang, erlang-nif

Is there a way to use a 32bit NIF from a 64 bit Erlang (under Windows)?

Seems impossible, but maybe there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265023/load-32bit-dll-library-in-64bit-application), so you might check there for answers. But why can't you just rebuild your NIF to be 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion (too silly) - you can write 32-bit out-of-proc port driver as wrapper of your NIF and run it in separate process. Of course, erlang node in this case should interact not with NIF but with external port program. But you can consider this as joke ;-)

Comment: Why joke? It is possible solution, but I want NIFs for their raw  performance without the cost of additional process