# QT load QLibrary user32

Tags: qt

Im trying to load `user32` in QT5 by doing:

```
    #include <qlibrary.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <lmcons.h>
    #include <process.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <userenv.h>
    #include <winuser.h>

    QLibrary *lib = new QLibrary("user32");



            QFunctionPointer p;
            if(lib->load() && (p = lib->resolve("GetLastInputInfo"))) {
                qDebug() << "Lib loaded";
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Lib could not load";
            }
```

But keep getting output "Lib could not load"

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Which part is returning false...`load()` or `resolve()`?

Comment: its `load()` where its stopping

Comment: print lib->errorString()

Comment: Loading may fail when you're trying to load a 32-bit library from a 64-bit application.  [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265023/load-32bit-dll-library-in-64bit-application) has some more info.

Comment: Not it all a suddenly loaded, did not change anything :s but unable to call: `lib->GetLastInputInfo()`