Adding a C++ DLL as a reference to C# works on x86 but fails on x64
Using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019:
Created a simple addition function in C++ to generate a DLL file.
In a new C# project, referenced the above DLL file.
Win32: For both the C++ DLL and the C# program, when the active platform is set to Win32, using 'Add reference' in the reference manager works. The project builds and runs without any issues.
x64: For both the C++ DLL and the C# program, when the active platform is set to x64, attempting to use 'Add reference' in the reference manager results in a pop-up error

and the reference is not added to the project.
For my work, I need to use x64. What settings should I adjust to make this possible?
CPP file:
#include "pch.h"
#include "Divide.h"

Divide::Divide(int x) {
    this->x = x;
}

int Divide::adding(int y) {
    return this->x + y;
}

int Divide::get() {
    return this->x;
}


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* Create(int x) {
    return (void*) new Divide(x);
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int DivideAdding(Divide * a, int y) {
    return a->adding(y);
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int DivideGet(Divide * a) {
    return a->get();
}

header file:
class Divide {
    int x;
public:
    Divide(int x);
    int adding(int y);
    int get();
};

In C#:
[DllImport("DivideDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr Create(int x);

        [DllImport("DivideDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int DivideAdding(IntPtr a, int y);

        [DllImport("DivideDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int DivideGet(IntPtr a);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IntPtr a = Create(5);
                int temp = DivideGet(a);
                Console.WriteLine("Initial:" + temp);
                DivideAdding(a, 10);

For my work, I need to use x64. What settings should I adjust to make this possible?
If you need more information, please let me know.

Try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265023/load-32-bit-dll-library-in-64-bit-application

You can't do that. No matter the language, you can only load a 32-bit DLL in a 32-bit process. Either recompile the C++ DLL to 64-bit or don't use x64

In addition to the architecture issue, 'Add reference' is supposed to be only for .NET dlls (e.g. C++/CLI). For native C++ dlls (of matching architecture) you should simply copy it to the output folder, and use PInvoke (as you already did).

Do you only need x64 or besides x86? The wording "For my work, I need to use x64." does not clearly exclude that you need a different bitness for this somewhere else.

The real mystery is that it works for x86.  That's not possible, a C++ dll needs to implement COM with an embedded type library or must be a C++/CLI .net assembly to allow "Add Reference" to work.  It is neither.  Just stop doing this, use Project > Add Existing Item instead.  Set the Copy to Output Directory property of the added item to "Copy if newer", that ensures that the CLR can find it at runtime.  x64 is just fine.

Your sample also has a  memory leak as there is no FreePointer function to destroy the Divide

In C# project, Add reference is for managed DLLs.
Adding a C++ unmanaged DLL will cause a warning or error.
Visual Studio 2022:


You need to copy the C++ DLL to the output folder. Project -> Add Existing Item . Set the Copy to Output Directory property of the added item to "Copy if newer",
And make sure the C# project architecture is consistent with the C++ DLL:  properties -> Build -> Target Platform
