# Read/Extract .Doc Document all text

Tags: c#

I want to extract all the text from the document .doc file.

I have only the `Stream` object AND `byte[]` of the .doc document.

Tried the NOIP but they having unstable ver for .doc.

So, i need so library or some code to read/extract the .doc document.

The soultion should not dependent of Ms.Office.

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338205%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at these options:

Use PInvokes or the Open XML SDK as described here:

[How to extract text from MS office documents in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011234/how-to-extract-text-from-ms-office-documents-in-c-sharp?rq=1)