# How to read docx files line by line with c#?

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I am trying to use Open XML library to read a docx file like this =

```
White Noise
Rain Sounds
1

Hot N*gga
Bobby Shmurda
2

Ric Flair Drip (& Metro Boomin)
21 Savage , Offset , Metro Boomin
3

Plastic
Jaden
4
```

my code is =

```
public static void OpenWordprocessingDocumentReadonly(string filepath)
        {
            // Open a WordprocessingDocument based on a filepath.
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, false))
            {
                // Assign a reference to the existing document body.  
                Body body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;


                Console.Write(body.InnerText);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

but readed string  is this =

```
White NoiseRain Sounds1Hot N*ggaBobby Shmurda2Ric Flair Drip (& Metro Boomin)21 Savage , Offset , Metro Boomin3PlasticJaden
```

How to read line by line ?

Comment: that is text not DOCX content.

Comment: What does your docx file *actually* look like?  It's not juts plain text like you've written.  XML is an element-based doc.  You will likely have to read element by element.

Comment: LMGTFY  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument?view=openxml-2.8.1

Comment: This text is in a docx file. But i find the problem. I make this docx file by copy and pasting from a text on google chrome browser. And browsers next line character(ENTER or \n) is not same as my keyboards next line character(and also Open XML Library's). I get element by element when i put an ENTER character between the strings on the file. So i think i must put an ENTER between all string data. Do you have another opinion ? @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: it is not really my practice to conduct consulting via comments on questions.

Comment: if you have manual line breaks instead of paragraphs, this answer seems to handle them https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535929/1383168

Comment: thanks i will use it @Slai

Answer (score 4):

To loop over paragraphs :

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, false))
{
    var paragraphs = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>();
    foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(paragraph.InnerText);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: In an organic collected docx data, your code will run correctly. But there is a problem, I make this docx file by copy and pasting from a text on google chrome browser. And browsers next line character(ENTER or \n) is not same as my keyboards next line character(and also Open XML Library's). I get element by element when i put an ENTER character between the strings on the file. So i put an ENTER between all string data.